# function CurrentPageURL() responds the name of action form and not the actual URL

Tags: php, forms, url, get, smarty

I have the following lines in the .php file of a tellform form:

```
// Gets the current URL
function CurrentPageURL()
{
    $pageURL = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '80' ? $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $pageURL;
}
$url = CurrentPageURL();
```

and somewhere down below the following:
    `$message = "Hi! blahblahblah : $url";`

also, in the .tpl file I have the following line:

```
<form id="tellform" action="tellafriend/processTell.php" method="post">
```

All is working, except that the email sent has the link for /tellafriend/processTell.php and not the actual link to the product like shown in browser.
What should I do to correct this thing?
thanks!

edit 1
here is the .js part about submiting email:

```
// Use Ajax to send everything to processTell.php
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("#send").attr("value", "Slanje...");
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            $(form).slideUp("fast");
            $("#response-tell").html(responseText).hide().slideDown("fast");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

**SOLVED**
So, thanks to IMSoP I solved the problem.
He explained where the problem occured, so finaly I got it.
I totaly removed this `function CurrentPageURL` lines and in the .tpl page of the form in question I inserted the following code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="urlToPutInEmail" value="<?php echo $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_id); ?>" />
```

while in the tellform.php file I called for varible `$urlToPutInEmail`.
the simple is that... 
notice, this is working on opencart framework.

thank again IMSoP !

Comment: Sorry, but you are not showing any email generation code, so it's difficult to help you with that.

Comment: @Raad, I have added some code... please check and advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS is not sending the e-mail, it is submitting the form to another PHP file (using `ajaxSubmit`).

As far as PHP is concerned, an AJAX request is just like any other page request - in this case, it's just like your form having a normal "Submit" button.

So if it is "tellafriend/processTell.php" that is receiving the form data and generating the e-mail, then the "current URL" while it is doing so will be "tellafriend/processTell.php".

If what you actually want is the URL from the page *before* (i.e. the one with the form on) you need to pass it as an extra field in the form (e.g. populate an `<input type="hidden">` with your PHP function).

Comment: thank you! that is exactly what is going on. since I not so familiar with this stuff (obviously), could you please explain in details what should I do?

Comment: Just add this to your form: `<input type="hidden" name="urlToPutInEmail" value="{$current_url}">`, where you've passed Smarty the result of `CurrentPageURL()` as a variable called 'current_url'

Comment: thanks, I am trying to make it work now... I think I have connected the variables right, but... where should I put `CurrentPageURL()` lines?

Comment: I can't really answer that without seeing your whole application! Basically, wherever you are building the page with the "tellform" on it.

Comment: it is opencart in question with MVC framework... So, tellform is showing in product pages templated from product.tpl file. I guess I should put there those `CurrentPageURL()` lines. Still, it gives errors, so I do not know... Perhaps I should make some changes in controller files as well...

Comment: solved! thank you IMSoP for hints. I will give the explanation in the first post.